# how to export vcs(calender event) as sms attachment on android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

In my app I need to attach the calender event as **.vcs** in SMS by `SmsManager`.

This is my code for without attachment of **vcs** file:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

How can i attach the vcs file by programmatically?

Is it possible to  do by `SmsManager` (that is programmatically send SMS)?